# Fiddle how to show only fiddler proxy traffic?

Tags: proxy, fiddler

I connected my iPad by Fiddler proxy and try to monitor traffic. But my PC generate too many traffic and I lost iPad traffic in very big list. How I can setup filter: "Show only fiddler proxy traffic"?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to hide all traffic from processes on your machine is to click the icon in the Fiddler status bar that says `All Processes` and change it to `Hide All`. This will hide all traffic from recognized processes on your PC, so that only the traffic coming from the IPAD will appear.

Comment: This currently also hides the requests coming through the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Rules -> Customize Rules.

Inside the OnBeforeRequest method (on the line below `static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session) {`), add the following:

```
// Only show traffic from another device, for example Android.
if (oSession.clientIP == "::ffff:127.0.0.1") {
    oSession.Ignore();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to turn off Capture and select All Processes at the bottom left. But it happened. However, I must say, I had to play with these settings a bit and to restart Fiddler. At the beginning, the results were not always consistent, and I am wondering if there is a bug where activating/deactivating the capture or selecting a filter does not always work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Change status bar value from All processes to Non-Browser. This will show you only proxy traffic.

Comment: Actually it will only hide browser traffic but may show traffic from other processes on the client.

Answer (score 0):

With Fiddler Everwhere, configure a new rule like this:

[Fiddler Everwhere rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vU8KI.png)

Thanks to @Joakim for the inspiration for this solution.